# Почему полоса прокрутки не растягивается на весь виджет?

Tags: python, tkinter

Почему полоса прокрутки не растягивается на весь виджет?

```
from tkinter import*
win=Tk()

tx=Text(win,width=60,heigh=20,font='14')
scr=Scrollbar(win,command=tx.yview)
tx.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)

tx.grid(row=0,column=0)
scr.grid(row=0,column=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `sticky='ns'` (прилипание к "северу" и "югу" ячейки) при размещении скролбара:

```
from tkinter import *
win=Tk()

tx=Text(win,width=60,heigh=20,font='14')
scr=Scrollbar(win, command=tx.yview)
tx.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)

tx.grid(row=0,column=0)
scr.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky='ns')

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Вы привязываете скролл к основному окну `Tk` вот и ваша проблема

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()

tx = tk.Text(win)
scr = tk.Scrollbar(tx, command=tx.yview)
win.update()
tx.place(x=0, y=0, w=win.winfo_width(), h=win.winfo_height())
scr.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
scr['command'] = tx.yview
tx.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
win.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Но я не понимаю как работает win = tk.   Tk() tx = tk.Text(win).   scr = tk.Scrollbar. Какие функции выполняет tk?

Comment: @A.Kross `tk` это тоже самое что писать перед классами `tkinter` просто так сказать упрощенный вариант неполного написания

Comment: как вы в ответе на мой вопрос загрузили окно tk где выполняется то что мне нужно?

Comment: @A.Kross не совсем понял что вы хотите сказать

Comment: как вы сделали и загрузили гифку которую вы мне прислали в ответе на вопрос

Comment: @A.Kross [Вот ссылка на прогу](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

Comment: Спасибо большое