# Использование scrollbar в python tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

Подскажите пжл, как привязать кнопки или большой текст к скролбару, чтобы была возможность пролистывать эти элементы, если они не "влезают" в размер окна. Покажите пжл, на конкретном примере.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему полоса прокрутки не растягивается на весь виджет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824187/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: `чтобы была возможность пролистывать эти элементы, если они не "влезают" в размер окна` - см. пример кода к этому вопросу: [Несколько фреймов в столбец и scrollbar к ним в Python tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496427/Несколько-фреймов-в-столбец-и-scrollbar-к-ним-в-python-tkinter)